# Gas COST for Contract Initialization

Tags: solidity, gas

I am trying to understand the difference in gas cost between `getTokenBalance` for the two contracts below.

In Example 1 `ERC20` is initialized once during the deployment of `SomeContract` as a part of the constructor, while in Example 2 `ERC20` is initialized every time during `getTokenBalance` invocation.

Is there a siginificant difference between Example 1 and Example 2 below ?

Example 1:

```
contract SomeContract {
   ERC20 erc;

  constructor(tokenAddress){
      erc = ERC20(tokenAddress)
  }


   getTokenBalance(address owner) returns (uint){
      return erc.balanceOf(owner);
   }
}
```

Example 2:

```
contract SomeContract {

   getTokenBalance(address tokenAddress, address owner) returns (uint){
      ERC20 erc = ERC20(tokenAddress);
      return erc.balanceOf(owner);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Gas costs are often dominated by storage. In this case, your first contract writes an address to storage, which costs 20,000 gas. The second contract doesn't do that.

Comment: Furthermore every byte (contract size) costs